# SQL collectively update table fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to collectively some fields to the same value if they meet the criteria in my where clause. So instead of the following:

```
    UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = Value1, Column2 = Value2
WHERE Some_Column = Some_Value
```

I need to do something like:

```
    UPDATE Table1
SET Column1, Column2 WHERE Some_Column = Some_Value
```

Comment: i dont understand what do you mean by second query

Comment: You would need to repeat the expression. i.e. `SET Column1 = X, Column2 = X` unless your RDBMS supports such quirky syntax (and even if such an RDBMS does actually exist such non standard syntax would probably be best avoided). What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Martin Smith, I am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to chain assignments as is possible in languages like `C#` where you can do `x = y = z = 4;` to set multiple variables to the same value.

The [`UPDATE` grammar](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) in MySQL is below

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

It does not support this. You need to repeat the expression

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Column1 = expr, Column2 = expr
WHERE Some_Column = Some_Value
```

Comment: You are very correct. I was thinking chaining and completely missed the simple approach you suggested. Thank you!